# How to remove special characters from input text

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I want to remove all special characters from input text as well as some restricted words.

Whatever the things I want to remove, that will come dynamically

(Let me clarify this: Whatever the words I need to exclude they will be provided dynamically - the user will decide what needs to be excluded. That is the reason I did not include regex. restricted_words_list (see my code) will get from the database just to check the code working or not I kept statically ),

but for demonstration purposes, I kept them in a String array to confirm whether my code is working properly or not.

```
public class TestKeyword {

    private static final String[] restricted_words_list={"@","of","an","^","#","<",">","(",")"};

    private static final Pattern restrictedReplacer;

    private static Set<String> restrictedWords = null;

    static {

        StringBuilder strb= new StringBuilder();

        for(String str:restricted_words_list){
            strb.append("\\b").append(Pattern.quote(str)).append("\\b|");
        }

        strb.setLength(strb.length()-1);
        restrictedReplacer = Pattern.compile(strb.toString(),Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

        strb = new StringBuilder();    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String inputText = "abcd abc@ cbda ssef of jjj t#he g^g an wh&at ggg<g ss%ss ### (()) D^h^D";
        System.out.println("inputText : " + inputText);
        String modifiedText = restrictedWordCheck(inputText);
        System.out.println("Modified Text : " + modifiedText);

    }

    public static String restrictedWordCheck(String input){
        Matcher m = restrictedReplacer.matcher(input);
        StringBuffer strb = new StringBuffer(input.length());//ensuring capacity

        while(m.find()){
            if(restrictedWords==null)restrictedWords = new HashSet<String>();
            restrictedWords.add(m.group());  //m.group() returns what was matched
            m.appendReplacement(strb,""); //this writes out what came in between matching words

            for(int i=m.start();i<m.end();i++)
                strb.append("");
        }
        m.appendTail(strb);
        return strb.toString();
    }
}
```

The output is :

inputText : abcd abc@ cbda ssef of jjj t#he g^g an wh&at ggg

Modified Text : abcd abc@ cbda ssef  jjj the gg  wh&at gggg ss%ss ### (()) DhD

Here the excluded words are **of** and **an**, but only some of the special characters, not all that I specified in `restricted_words_list`

---

Now I got a better Solution:

```
    String inputText = title;// assigning input 
    List<String> restricted_words_list = catalogueService.getWordStopper(); // getting all stopper words from database dynamically (inside getWordStopper() method just i wrote a query and getting list of words)
    String finalResult = "";
    List<String> stopperCleanText = new ArrayList<String>();

    String[] afterTextSplit = inputText.split("\\s"); // split and add to list

    for (int i = 0; i < afterTextSplit.length; i++) {
        stopperCleanText.add(afterTextSplit[i]); // adding to list
    }

    stopperCleanText.removeAll(restricted_words_list); // remove all word stopper 

    for (String addToString : stopperCleanText)
    {
        finalResult += addToString+";"; // add semicolon to cleaned text 
    }

    return finalResult;
```

Comment: It is doing exactly what you're asking it to do.. what would be your expected `Modified Text`?

Comment: no it's not does see : input : abc@ output : abc@ even though restricted_words_list have '@' and if i give anly special character then it wont work like wise... pleas check by executing code if possibal

Comment: Should the `###` be removed as well? Or only single instances of the `restricted_words_list`?

Comment: see what ever the words restricted_words_list have that should not present in result i.e in modified-text (what ever it takes)

Comment: Try my solution from below, I put an answer there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your loop

```
for(String str:restricted_words_list){
        strb.append("\\b").append(Pattern.quote(str)).append("\\b|");
}
```

to this:

```
for(String str:restricted_words_list){
        strb.append("\\b*").append(Pattern.quote(str)).append("\\b*|");
}
```

Because with your loop you're matching the `restricted_words_list` elements only if there is something before **and** after the match. Since `abc@` does not have anything after the `@` it will not be replaced. If you add `*` (which means 0 or more occurences) to the `\\b` on either side it will match things like `abc@` as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
public String replaceAll(String regex,
                         String replacement)
```

Replaces each substring of this string (which matches the given regular expression) with the given replacement.

Parameters:

- `regex` - the regular expression to which this string is to be
  matched
- `replacement` - the string to be substituted for each match.

So you just need to provide replacement parameter with an empty String.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider to use Regex directly to replace those special character with empty ''? Check it out: [Java; String replace (using regular expressions)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632204/java-string-replace-using-regular-expressions), some tutorial here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: sorry let me clear this. What ever the words i need to exclude that will come dynamically i.e user will decide what need to exclude that's the reason i not included regx. restricted_words_list (see my code) will get from database just to check the code working or not i kept statically

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this :

```
    String inputText = "abcd abc@ cbda ssef of jjj t#he g^g an wh&at ggg<g ss%ss ### (()) D^h^D";        
    String regx="([^a-z^ ^0-9]*\\^*)";        
    String textWithoutSpecialChar=inputText.replaceAll(regx,"");
    System.out.println("Without Special Char:"+textWithoutSpecialChar);

    String yourSetofString="of|an";   // your restricted words.      
    String op=textWithoutSpecialChar.replaceAll(yourSetofString,"");
    System.out.println("output : "+op);
```

o/p :

```
Without Special Char:abcd abc cbda ssef of jjj the gg an what gggg ssss   h

output : abcd abc cbda ssef  jjj the gg  what gggg ssss   h
```

Comment: what ever the words i need to exclude that will come dynamically i.e user will decide what need to exclude that's the reason i not included regx. restricted_words_list (see my code) will get from database just to check the code working or not i kept statically

Comment: Not a problem . You create the regx dynamically taking words from DB then  use that regx to replace it

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "abcd abc@ cbda ssef of jjj t#he g^g an wh&at ggg (blah) and | then";

String[] words = new String[]{ " of ", "|", "(", " an ", "#", "@", "&", "^", ")" };
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for( String w : words ) {
    if( w.length() == 1 ) {
        sb.append( "\\" );
    }
    sb.append( w ).append( "|" );
}
System.out.println( s.replaceAll( sb.toString(), "" ) );
```

Comment: what ever the words i need to exclude that will come dynamically i.e user will decide what need to exclude that's the reason i not included regx. restricted_words_list (see my code) will get from database just to check the code working or not i kept statically