# Want to remove the tags from the String

Tags: java, regex, string, tags

I have the below string which contains some custom tags. I want to remove those custom tags from the String. Could you please help me how to remove the tags.

```
 String temp = "[p]test to remove tags started with braces [B]bold text [/B][I]italic text [/I] [U]underlined Text[/U] bla bla [/P]"
```

Comment: `temp = temp.replace("[B]","")`

Comment: You are welcome :) . BTW have you tried anything?

Comment: `temp = temp.replaceAll("\\[/?\\w\\]","")` maybe?

Comment: If my answer worked for you would you be able to use the tick next to the answer to accept it? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily enough with [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), which accepts a regular expression.

```
temp = temp.replaceAll("\\[/?\\w\\]","")
```

`\\[` means a literal left square bracket.
`/?` means an optional forward slash.
`\\w` means a word character (such as a letter).
`\\]` means a literal right square bracket.

This sequence in combination should match all the tags you listed in your question, and replacing them with the empty string will effectively remove them.

Comment: Out of interest is mine or yours more efficient?

Comment: Probably mine since it doesn't have `*` in it, but I couldn't say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You could use replace() for every set of characters that you want to remove like this :

```
temp = temp.replace("[p]", "");
temp = temp.replace("[B]", "");
temp = temp.replace("[/B]", "");
temp = temp.replace("[I]", "");
temp = temp.replace("[/I]", "");
temp = temp.replace("[U]", "");
temp = temp.replace("[/U]", "");
temp = temp.replace("[/P]", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String cleanedString = temp.replaceAll("\\[[a-zA-Z\\/]+\\]", "");
```

Comment: This does not work as it is java and you have several illegal escape characters

Comment: Yes, sorry, forgot the double backslash

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions so far have been messy and take up multiple lines because they address each [] individually. This regex, `\\[(.*?)\\]`, handles them all at once

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String temp = "[p]test to remove tags started with braces [B]bold text [/B][I]italic text [/I] [U]underlined Text[/U] bla bla [/P]";
        temp = temp.replaceAll("\\[(.*?)\\]","");
        System.out.println(temp);
    }
}
```

A brilliant website for regexes is [regex101](https://regex101.com/). This allows you to test your own regexes to see if they work and how the work. For the one given above, [click here](https://regex101.com/r/zP5jT9/1), works like this.

- `\\[` Matches the character `[` literally
- `(.*?)` is a capturing group which matches any, excluding new line characters.

  - `*?` is a lazy quantifier which matches all the characters inbetween `[]` in this case
- `\\]` Matches the character `]` literally

Answer (score -1):

What I would do is to make a regular expression and use the method `replace_all()` like so:

```
temp.replaceAll("\\[[a-zA-Z\\/]+\\]", "");
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632204/java-string-replace-using-regular-expressions) may help you.

Use this to make your own regex and test it : [Regex Tester](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)