# Replace all regex matches in String with substring of match

Tags: java

Just wondering if there's a nicer solution to this given a String such as

```
xDLMContent <matches> something <and> dSecurityGroup <contains> somethingelse <and> xDLMSomeOtherMetaDataField <matches> anothersomethingelse
```

It needs to be replaced with

```
DLMContent <matches> something <and> SecurityGroup <contains> somethingelse <and> DLMSomeOtherMetaDataField <matches> anothersomethingelse
```

Rule being metadata fields begin with x or d followed by uppercase letter and then 1 or more mixed case alpha characters.

Here's my solution but I'm wondering if there's something better

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "xDLMContent <matches> something <and> dSecurityGroup <contains> somethingelse <and> xDLMSomeOtherMetaDataField <matches> anothersomethingelse";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[dx][A-Z][a-zA-Z]+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.match(s);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String orig = s.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end());
        String rep = s.substring(matcher.start() + 1, matcher.end());
        s = s.replaceAll(orig, rep);
        matcher = pattern.match(s);
    }

    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632204/java-string-replace-using-regular-expressions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `replaceAll()` works well. Just pick what you want to keep ( the part in brackets `()` ), and replace by using `$1`

```
String f = s.replaceAll("[dx]([A-Z][a-zA-Z]+)", "$1");
```

Output

```
DLMContent <matches> something <and> SecurityGroup <contains> somethingelse <and> DLMSomeOtherMetaDataField <matches> anothersomethingelse
```

Comment: Do you know whether there is a possibility to perform some transformation on this group, like so: `replaceAll("[dx]([A-Z][a-zA-Z]+)", someMethod("$1"))` ? (obviously, this code does not work - maybe there is some other trick to this)

Comment: @AlexSemeniuk I have added an answer that has the ability to apply some additional transformation to the group. (The downside is that it only works in Java 9 or newer.)

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 9 [Matcher.replaceAll(Function)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.Function-) is available on the [Matcher class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html). If you want to do some extra transformation on the matched groups, then you can do something like this:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Playground {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "xDLMContent <matches> something <and> dSecurityGroup <contains> somethingelse <and> xDLMSomeOtherMetaDataField <matches> anothersomethingelse";
        String output = Pattern.compile("[dx]([A-Z][a-zA-Z]+)").matcher(input).replaceAll(m -> transformation(m.group(1)));
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    public static String transformation(String input) {
        return input.concat("-extra");
    }
}
```

This will print:

```
DLMContent-extra <matches> something <and> SecurityGroup-extra <contains> somethingelse <and> DLMSomeOtherMetaDataField-extra <matches> anothersomethingelse
```

Some more info:

- `m.group()` gives you the whole matched value: `[dx]([A-Z][a-zA-Z]+)` for example `xDLMContent`
- `m.group(1)` gives you the first group of the matched value: `([A-Z][a-zA-Z]+)` for example `DLMContent`

If you don't need the additional transformation, then you can just do:

```
.replaceAll(m -> m.group(1))
```