# Add Something to Char Array at Specific Spot (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, char, addition

I am tasked with taking a user sentence then separating it at the upper case letters as well as making those letters lower case after adding a `" "`.
I want to add a space add that position so that if user inputs `"HappyDaysToCome"` will output `"Happy days to come"`.

#### Current code

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a sentence");
    String sentenceString = s.nextLine();
    char[] sentenceArray = sentenceString.toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < sentenceArray.length; i++)
    {
        if(i!=0 && Character.isUpperCase(sentenceArray[i]))
        {
            Character.toLowerCase(sentenceArray[i]); 
            sentenceArray.add(i, ' ');    
        }

    }
    System.out.println(sentenceArray)
    s.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't insert things into arrays since they are fixed length. You should use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: This would be much simpler with regular expressions. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632204/java-string-replace-using-regular-expressions).

Answer (score 1):

There is no `add` method for arrays. Arrays are not resizeable. If you indeed want to use a `char[]` array, you need to allocate one that is large enough, e.g. by counting the uppercase letters or simply by allocating a array that is surely large enough (twice the `String` length minus 1).

```
String input = ...

String outputString;

if (input.isEmpty()) {
    outputString = "";
} else {
    char[] output = new char[input.length() * 2 - 1];
    output[0] = input.charAt(0);
    int outputIndex = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < input.length(); i++, outputIndex++) {
        char c = input.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
            output[outputIndex++] = ' ';
            output[outputIndex] = Character.toLowerCase(c);
        } else {
            output[outputIndex] = c;
        }
    }
    outputString = new String(output, 0, outputIndex);
}

System.out.println(outputString);
```

---

Or better still use a `StringBuilder`

```
String input = ...

String outputString;

if (input.isEmpty()) {
    outputString = "";
} else {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder().append(input.charAt(0));

    for (int i = 1; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char c = input.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
            sb.append(' ').append(Character.toLowerCase(c));
        } else {
            sb.append(c);
        }
    }
    outputString = sb.toString();
}

System.out.println(outputString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're approaching this the wrong way. Just add each char back to a new string but with spaces included at the right spots. Don't worry about modifying your char array at all. Here is a slight modification of your code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a sentence");
    String sentenceString = s.nextLine();
    char[] sentenceArray = sentenceString.toCharArray();

    //new string to hold the output
    //starts with only the first char of the old string
    string spacedString = sentenceArray[0] + "";

    for(int i = 1; i < sentenceArray.length; i++)
    {
      if(Character.isUpperCase(sentenceArray[i]))
      {
        //if we find an upper case char, add a space and the lower case of that char
        spacedString = spacedString + " " + Character.toLowerCase(sentenceArray[i]);    
      }else {
        //otherwise just add the char itself
        spacedString = spacedString + sentenceArray[i];
      }
    }

    System.out.println(spacedString)
    s.close();
  }
```

If you want to optimize performance, you can use a `StringBuilder` object. However, for spacing out a single sentence, performance isn't going to make any real difference at all. If performance does matter to you, read more on `StringBuilder` here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

Comment: You know this is really inefficient, right? Don't concatenate strings in a loop, use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Seems to me like the author has a simple assignment and is looking for the simplest way to solve it. This isn't a question about efficiency; we are dealing with a single sentence. Efficiency is pretty much irrelevant for this use case.

Comment: that OP doesn't ask for an efficient solution doesn't mean that you should give them an inefficient one. Use a `StringBuilder` to accumulate the String; it hardly changes the structure.

Comment: @AndyTurner I repeat - for what the OP is asking for, performance is irrelevant.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with creating examples that are "best practices". Especially if you want up-votes for an otherwise acceptable answer. No need to be obstinate; it was a legitimate suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

We basically want to tokenize the input string on uppercase letters. This can be done using the regular expression `[A-Z][^A-Z]*` (i.e., one uppercase, followed by zero or more "not" uppercase). The `String` class has a built-in `split()` method that takes a regular expression. Unfortunately, you also want to keep the delimiter (which is the uppercase letter), so that slightly complicates matters, but it can still be done using `Pattern` and `Matcher` to put the matched delimiter back into the string:

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Foo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "ThisIsATest1234ABC";
    String regex = "\\p{javaUpperCase}[^\\p{javaUpperCase}]*";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text);
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(matcher.find()){
        matcher.appendReplacement(buf, matcher.group());
        result.add(buf.toString());
        buf.setLength(0);
    }   

    matcher.appendTail(buf);
    result.add(buf.toString());
    String resultString = ""; 
    for(String s: result) { resultString += s + " "; }
    System.out.println("Final: \"" + resultString.trim() + "\"");
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Final: "This Is A Test1234 A B C"
```