# delete only two brackets after delimiter

Tags: java, regex, split

I have a String java like this :

```
String query= Select * from table where date between ('2016-05-03' and '2016-05-04' )
```

I wanted to delete brackets after between i tried :

```
 String search="between";
if(query.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) != -1){  
query=query.replaceAll("[()]","");
 }
```

It worked but If the query contains some brackets after or before the word 'between' they will be delete also.. Example :

```
SELECT column-names
 FROM table-name1
WHERE value IN (SELECT date 
               FROM table-name2 
              WHERE date between ('2016-05-03' and '2016-05-04' ))
```

I just want to delete  two first brackets after the word 'between' to get this :

```
 SELECT column-names
 FROM table-name1
WHERE value IN (SELECT date 
               FROM table-name2 
              WHERE date between '2016-05-03' and '2016-05-04')
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java; String replace (using regular expressions)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632204/java-string-replace-using-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can represent in regex the whole structure you're trying to change :

```
between\s*\(([^)]*)\)
```

and transform it into

```
between $1
```

Where `$1` is a reference to the `[^)]*` group which catches the content of the brackets.

The transformation will only occur if the `between` is followed by an open bracket and will remove the closest closing bracket.

[See it in action !](https://ideone.com/By2mSK)

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the first `(` after `between` and the last occurrence of `)` after `(`. That means, you need to leverage greedy matching `.*` with DOTALL modifier so that the `.` could match linebreak symbols. Also, a `[^(]*` can help you grab anything that is not `(` between `between` and the `(`:

```
String s = "SELECT column-names\n FROM table-name1\nWHERE value IN (SELECT date \n               FROM table-name2 \n              WHERE date between ('2016-05-03' and '2016-05-04' ))";
String search="(?s)(between[^(]*)\\((.*)\\)";
System.out.println(s.replaceFirst(search, "$1$2"));
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/X92G0i)

**Details**:

- `(?s)` - the embedded DOTALL flag
- `(between[^(]*)` - Group 1 capturing `between` and 0+ chars other than `(`
- `\\(` - a `(` is matched
- `(.*)` -  any 0+ chars as many as possible up to the last
- `\\)` -  literal `)`.

The `$1` references to the Group 1 contents, and `$2` to the Group 2  contents.

Answer (score 1):

I think below piece of code will solve your problem:

```
String query= "Select * from table where date between ('2016-05-03' and '2016-05-04')";
StringBuilder sbr = new StringBuilder(query);
sbr.deleteCharAt(sbr.indexOf("(", sbr.indexOf("between")));
sbr.deleteCharAt(sbr.indexOf(")", sbr.indexOf("between")));
query= sbr.toString();
```