# Using Regular Expression in Java to extract information from a String

Tags: java, regex, string

I have one input `String` like this:

```
"I am Duc/N Ta/N Van/N"
```

String `"/N"` present it is the Name of one person.
The expected output is:

> Name: Duc Ta Van

How can I do it by using regular expression?

Comment: Do you want `Name: Duc Ta Van` as result or  `/N: Duc Ta Van`? Are the literals Duc, Ta and Van always the same?

Comment: Can you at least try a bit ? We are not here to provide you the solution but to help you find it... Without an effort, I don't want to help you. See [ask]

Comment: @ zᴉɹɥƆ: yeap, I would like Name: Duc Ta Van as the result

Comment: u can call a replace the \n whit another charArray
String.replace("\\n", " ")

Comment: Possible duplicate [Java; String replace (using regular expressions)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632204/java-string-replace-using-regular-expressions)

Comment: @AxelH: Can you privide me one recommend to solve it. Because of urgency

Comment: Urgency ? Unless this is an for an health application linked to an important surgery equipment, there is no urgency... See the duplicate to see how to use a regex to "replace" values in a `String`. The regex is simple to write after that.

Comment: Please see: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Pattern and Matcher like this :

```
String input = "I am Duc/N Ta/N Van/N";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([^\\s]+)/N");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
String result = "";
while (matcher.find()) {
    result+= matcher.group(1) + " ";
}

System.out.println("Name: " + result.trim());
```

Output

```
Name: Duc Ta Van
```

---

### Another Solution using Java 9+

From Java9+ you can use [`Matcher::results`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results--) like this :

```
String input = "I am Duc/N Ta/N Van/N";
String regex = "([^\\s]+)/N";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
String result = matcher.results().map(s -> s.group(1)).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

System.out.println("Name: " + result); // Name: Duc Ta Van
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @YCF_L

Comment: That java 9 solution is excellent. I really need to update my systems!

Comment: This is correct @AxelH it is the time for us to move to Java 10 :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the regex to use to capture every "name" preceded by a `/N`

```
(\w+)\/N
```

Validate with [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rQyNPs/2)

Now, you just need to loop on every match in that `String` and concatenate the to get the result :

```
String pattern = "(\\w+)\\/N";
String test = "I am Duc/N Ta/N Van/N";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(test);

StringBuilder sbNames = new StringBuilder(); 
while(m.find()){
    sbNames.append(m.group(1)).append(" ");
}
System.out.println(sbNames.toString());
```

> Duc Ta Van

It is giving you the hardest part. I let you adapt this to match your need.

*Note :*
In java, it is not required to escape a forward slash, but to use the same regex in the entire answer, I will keep `"(\\w+)\\/N"`, but `"(\\w+)/N"` will work as well.

Comment: Yeah I notice that... strangely regex101 asked for "/" to be escaped ... Since it was working I kept it in the java to use the same regex and kept the link to show the dynamic match. But thanks @YCF_L EDIT: this is the delimiter for the flags... I am stupid ;) java doesn't support them.

Answer (score 0):

I've used "[/N]+" as the regular expression.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yH1uxi/1/)

`[]` = Matches characters inside the set

`\/` = Matches the character `/` literally (case sensitive)

`+` = Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

Comment: P.S. This regex can be used to remove `/N` out of the string.

Comment: You will still find the rest of the `String` that is not followed by `/N` and that is not a name. n the example `I am ` is not needed.

Comment: AxelH I haven't touched regex since 2nd year of college, my bad :)

Comment: That's not about the regex, but about the question itself. It is not only the remove `/N` but to extract the word before every `/N`.

Comment: Ahh okay. I re-read the question there! Cheers. Does `(\w+)` do the actual grouping/extraction?

Comment: Yep, that's one solution. (That's the one I used)