# Convert a particular String format to json

Tags: java, json, data-conversion

I have this form of data below and I want to convert it into json using java

The problem that the string contains brackets for objects and numbers which means the array ordering...

```
status=accepted&results[0][id]=7&results[0][name]=data&results[0][score]=9&results[1][name]=data2&results[1][score]=7&results[1][id]=8&reports[0][name]=data1&reports[0][id]=1&reports[0][is_available]=1&reports[1][id]=2&reports[1][name]=data&email=test@test.com
```

Thanks

Comment: How your getting this data ? And please post your attempts here.

Comment: Maybe one of these [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13592236/8547799) will do the trick.

Comment: @SudhirOjha I get this data as an input from an external API, my attempts doesn't work no need to post here, I tried to create an object and get this String as object in requestBody but doesn't work cause of brackets, and if i will split an do the conversion manually it will take some lines of code, so i'm asking if there is another way...

Answer (score 1):

If the pattern is fixed, Regular expressions can be used to check the pattern and replace to form JSON.

Check [Pattern Replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632204/java-string-replace-using-regular-expressions)

Might have to code, depending upon the use case.

E.g., if 2D array elements like results[0][id] have to be converted

{
  "results": {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "data"
  }
}

Comment: If the pattern is fixed  like "=" to ":" and "&" to ",". But for results code will be required.