# How to use .replace and regex to only change matches from original string like with javascript

Tags: java, function, replace, str-replace

An example of the string is `1-2.5.6/8/3.4?1=f-g&e=d&h=i` and in JavaScript the code `p = p.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + '\\w+' + '\\b', 'g'), k[c])` will replace the characters 1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 3, 4, 1, f, g, e, d, h, and i with their respective string that is returned from the k[c], a function which just takes the character from the string and returns another value from a dictionary. I am trying to implement the same thing in Java, but some of the replaced characters have characters like 1, 2, 5, 6, 8, etc. So `delivery45-2.5.6/8/3.4?1=f-g&e=d&h=i` will turn into `STRINGelivery45-2.5.6/8/3.4?1=f-g&e=d&h=i`. Is there a to implement the same thing in Java as it does in JavaScript?

Here is what I am currently using in Java:

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b\\w+\\b");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(p);
while (matcher.find()) {
    String matchedString = matcher.group();
    String replacementString = z.apply(String.valueOf(matchedString));
    p = p.replace(matchedString, replacementString);
}
```

p being the original string, and z acting like k[c].

The result ends up being something like `STRING_tliv56287592ry45-2.5.6/8/3.4?1=f-g&e=d&h=i` which goes until it can't replace anymore.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java; String replace (using regular expressions)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632204/java-string-replace-using-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.
I created 1 ArrayLists with:

```
ArrayList<Integer> listint = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then with the regex matcher I got the index value of the matches and added them to the list

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b\\w+\\b");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(p);
while (matcher.find()) {
                listint.add(matcher.start());
}
```

Then I used a for loop to go over the Arraylist to replace the original string from right to left because if you did it from left to right it would shift the index values which would ruin the string.

```
for (int i = listint.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                String startz = p.substring(0, listint.get(i));
                String middle = liststr.get(i);
                String endz = p.substring(listint.get(i) + 1);
                p = startz + middle + endz;
            }
```

Comment: This is not a good (efficient) solution. You can do the replacement using a `Matcher` and a `StringBuffer` (in more recent version, also `StringBuilder`). See the documentation of [`Matcher.appendReplacement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement(java.lang.StringBuilder,java.lang.String))